# Index rebuild/reorg did not decrease the avg percent fragmentation

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am using this sproc to rebuild and defrag.  It works but some tables still have a high percent of fragmentation.

```
Index           alloc_unit_type_desc        avg_fragmentation_in_percent    page_count
PK_AccessPoint      IN_ROW_DATA              33.3333333333333                    3
```

Here is the link to the sproc

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2016/07/03/how-to-maintain-azure-sql-indexes-and-statistics/

why is the table avg fragmentation still at 33%?
The sproc ran multiple times.  Other tables went to 0%.  I simply do not know what is going on.

Query for indexes and fragmentation:

```
SELECT dbschemas.[name] as 'Schema', 
dbtables.object_id,
dbtables.[name] as 'Table', 
dbindexes.[name] as 'Index',
indexstats.alloc_unit_type_desc,
indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
indexstats.page_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
INNER JOIN sys.tables dbtables on dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas dbschemas on dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS dbindexes ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
WHERE indexstats.database_id = DB_ID()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small tables, usually performance impact on fragmentation is undetectable. The first 8 page allocation would be from mixed extents and mixed extents could be anywhere in database files. Rebuilding indexes would not change this nature.

If you have a small table, those mixed pages weight a lot during fragmentation calculation; therefore, rebuilding index may not reduce fragmentation. (As matter of fact, I could easily construct a case that fragmentation increases after rebuild.) Those fragmentation would not be a pain for your query performance; so basically you can ignore

Reason as to why fragmentation remains for small index even after rebuild is that after rebuild the pages which are allocated to index is from  Mixed extent. A mixed extent contains mixed pages and extent is collection of 8 pages, these are always  the first 8 pages which would be allocated to database when it requires pages to write information. The first 8 pages will always be from mixed extent and after that it would allocate  Uniform extents. Reason for allocating first 8 pages from mixed extent is database engine assumes that its quite possible table would be small(at the beginning) and there would not be much advantage in allocating uniform extent, so it internally decides to allocate first  8 pages from mixed extent. As the 8 pages limit is crossed it would start allocating Uniform extents.  As the mixed extent is not allocated to any particular IAM chain, this means that it may hold pages allocated to possibly 8 separate IAM . This is very important fact. The first 8 pages allocated by mixed extent could be scattered anywhere and this is what accounts for fragmentation even after rebuild.

For more information, please read [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28182.sql-server-in-depth-what-can-cause-index-to-be-still-fragmented-after-rebuild.aspx) article.